# Laravel 6 relation with()

Tags: eloquent, laravel-6, has-many

I have a Posts model which has many Comments and every comment has one User model.
If I run

```
@foreach( $post->comments as $comment )
    <div>{{ $comment->text }} <br>{ $comment->user->name }}</div>
@endforeach
```

it generates one query to user for every loop in comments foreach. How to write this code so the Laravel makes only one query for all users?

Controller code looks like

```
public function detail(Post $post)
{
    return view('home.detail')->with([
        'post' => $post->with('comments', 'comments.user')->get()->first()
    ]);
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `$post = Post::with('comments','comments.users')->...`

Comment: I am getting $post by dependency injection. Look at question update. This makes query for all users in one but also makes queries for every user separately.

Comment: also this makes a redundant query for all posts comments. select * from `comments` where `comments`.`post_id` in (1, 2, 3)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading